# Rails: Force empty string to NULL in the database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is there an easy way (i.e. a configuration) to force ActiveRecord to save empty strings as NULL in the DB (if the column allows)?

The reason for this is that if you have a NULLable string column in the DB without a default value, new records that do not set this value will contain NULL, whereas new records that set this value to the empty string will not be NULL, leading to inconsistencies in the database that I'd like to avoid.

Right now I'm doing stuff like this in my models:

```
before_save :set_nil

def set_nil
  [:foo, :bar].each do |att|
    self[att] = nil if self[att].blank?
  end
end
```

which works but isn't very efficient or DRY. I could factor this out into a method and mix it into ActiveRecord, but before I go down that route, I'd like to know if there's a way to do this already.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try if this gem works:

https://github.com/rubiety/nilify_blanks

> Provides a framework for saving incoming blank values as nil in the database in instances where you'd rather use DB NULL than simply a blank string...
>
> In Rails when saving a model from a form and values are not provided by the user, an empty string is recorded to the database instead of a NULL as many would prefer (mixing blanks and NULLs can become confusing). This plugin allows you to specify a list of attributes (or exceptions from all the attributes) that will be converted to nil if they are blank before a model is saved.
>
> Only attributes responding to blank? with a value of true will be converted to nil. Therefore, this does not work with integer fields with the value of 0, for example...

Comment: I ended up using [attribute_normalizer](https://github.com/mdeering/attribute_normalizer), which does nilification and a lot more besides, such as stripping whitespace, out of the box.

Answer (score 59):

Yes, the only option at the moment is to use a callback.

```
before_save :normalize_blank_values

def normalize_blank_values
  attributes.each do |column, value|
    self[column].present? || self[column] = nil
  end
end
```

You can convert the code into a mixin to easily include it in several models.

```
module NormalizeBlankValues
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save :normalize_blank_values
  end

  def normalize_blank_values
    attributes.each do |column, value|
      self[column].present? || self[column] = nil
    end
  end

end

class User
  include NormalizeBlankValues
end
```

Or you can define it in ActiveRecord::Base to have it in all your models.

Finally, you can also include it in ActiveRecord::Base but enable it when required.

```
module NormalizeBlankValues
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def normalize_blank_values
    attributes.each do |column, value|
      self[column].present? || self[column] = nil
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def normalize_blank_values
      before_save :normalize_blank_values
    end
  end

end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, NormalizeBlankValues)

class User
end

class Post
  normalize_blank_values

  # ...
end
```

Comment: Looks good, thanks. Would it make sense to build this as a gem while I'm at it? I can't imagine I'm the only one with this problem.

Comment: In your mixin code - does simply writing `NormalizeBlankValues` in the `User` model work? Don't you need to `include NormalizeBlankValues`?

Comment: @Chowlett It was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: @Thilo I wrote this piece of code in less than a couple of minutes. If a gem would exist, I wouldn't probably add the overhead of a new Gem just for such this code. If you want to package it as a gem you can do, but to me this solution seems too localized to your problem.

Comment: before_filter is a controller method. I had to change to before_save to support ActiveRecords. Also, the method doesn't treat well booleans. Consider adding a test case if the column type is string (and maybe others) before setting to nil

Comment: @SimoneCarletti but one thing.. `false.present? == false`,  `false.to_s.present? == true`. It is important for model fields, which by default should be boolean (e.g. false)

Comment: Also, instead of writing `self[column].present? || self[column] = nil` you could use a the `.presence` method like so: `self[column] = self[column].presence`

Answer (score 19):

Another option is to provide custom setters, instead of handling this in a hook. E.g.:

```
def foo=(val)
  super(val == "" ? nil : val)
end
```

Comment: This solution is much simpler (assuming you want to do this for a specific field).

Comment: This solution is so simple and idiomatic that I'm kicking myself for not thinking of it and using callbacks instead

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion:

```
# app/models/contact_message.rb
class ContactMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  include CommonValidations
  include Shared::Normalizer
end


# app/models/concerns/shared/normalizer.rb
module Shared::Normalizer
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save :nilify_blanks
  end

  def nilify_blanks
    attributes.each do |column, value|
      # ugly but work
      # self[column] = nil if !self[column].present? && self[column] != false

      # best way
      #
      self[column] = nil if self[column].kind_of? String and self[column].empty?
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Slight style update: `self[column] = nil if self[column].is_a?(String) && self[column].empty?`

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for necroposting, but I didn't find exact thing here in answers, if you need solution to **specify** fields which should be nilified:

```
module EnforceNil
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def enforce_nil(*args)
      self.class_eval do
        define_method(:enforce_nil) do
          args.each do |argument|
            field=self.send(argument)
            self.send("#{argument}=", nil)  if field.blank?
          end
        end           
        before_save :enforce_nil
      end
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, EnforceNil)
```

This way:

```
class User
  enforce_nil :phone #,:is_hobbit, etc  
end
```

Enforcing certain field is handy when let's say you have field1 and field2. Field1 has unique index in SQL, but can be blank, so you need enforcement(NULL considered unique, "" - not by SQL), but for field2 you don't actually care and you have already dozens of callbacks or methods, which work when field2 is "", but will dig your app under the layer of errors if field2 is `nil`. Situation I faced with.

May be useful for someone.

Answer (score 3):

### [Strip Attributes Gem](https://github.com/rmm5t/strip_attributes)

There's a handy gem that does this automatically when saving a record, whether that's in a user form or in the console or in a rake task, etc.

It's called **[strip_attributes](https://github.com/rmm5t/strip_attributes)** and is extremely easy to use, with sane defaults right out of the box.

It does two main things by default that should *almost* always be done:

1. Strip leading and trailing white space:

   ```
   " My Value " #=> "My Value"
   ```
2. Turn empty Strings into `NULL`:

   ```
   ""  #=> NULL
   " " #=> NULL
   ```

#### Install

You can add it to your gem file with:

`gem strip_attributes`

#### Usage

Add it to any (or all) models that you want to strip leading/trailing whitespace from and turn empty strings into `NULL`:

```
class DrunkPokerPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  strip_attributes
end
```

#### Advanced Usage

There are additional options that you can pass on a per-Model basis to handle exceptions, like if you want to retain leading/trailing white space or not, etc.

You can view all of the options on the GitHub repository here:

https://github.com/rmm5t/strip_attributes#examples

Answer (score 0):

I use the [attribute normalizer](https://github.com/mdeering/attribute_normalizer) gem to normalize attributes before they into the db.