# Rails: test if a column allows nil values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This answer to [Rails: Force empty string to NULL in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7202438/134367) suggests using a mixin to set empty string column values to nil.

Is there a way to test if the column accepts nil/null values?

```
> f = Foobar.find(1)
=> #<Entity id: 7, name: "foo", description: nil, has_bar: false, created_at: "2014-08-04 21:50:42", updated_at: "2014-08-05 19:35:33">

> f.has_bar.allow_nil?
NoMethodError: undefined method `allow_nil?' for nil:NilClass
```

I want to ensure that the `description` field is `nil` not a blank string, but ensure that `has_bar` is either `true` or `false`.

Excerpt from other question:

```
attributes.each do |column, value|
  # invalid syntax
  ( self[column].present? && self[column].allow_nil? ) || self[column] = nil
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f.description.nil? && (f.has_bar == true || f.has_bar == false)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Use [`#columns_hash`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/columns_hash)

I had the same question and didn't find an answer anywhere so I went digging into the Rails classes and methods available and found something that did the trick.

`columns_hash` is what you're looking for. Simply call it on your model class and it'll give you a list of the columns and various properties, including `@null`, which tells you if `NULL` values are accepted.

```rb
Foobar.columns_hash[ "id" ]
#=> #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MySQL::Column:0x0000000138ff8c08
 @collation=nil,
 @comment=nil,
 @default=nil,
 @default_function=nil,
 @name="id",
 @null=false,
 @sql_type_metadata=
  #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SqlTypeMetadata:0x0000000138ff8ca8
   @limit=8,
   @precision=nil,
   @scale=nil,
   @sql_type="bigint unsigned",
   @type=:integer>>

Foobar.columns_hash[ "id" ].null
#=> false
```

Comment:  Should I make an unnecessary edit this to this answer that comments out the rest of the column object return, thus removing the color-coding and rendering it a less readable and inaccurate reflection of the result of running the command, or is that the type of unnecessary pedantic thing that men only try to do to women's answers?

Comment: @Allison If you think something would be more readable then go ahead and propose the edit. I _think_ my intention with including it is to show you what is returned from `columns_hash` so the reader would have more of an understanding of what is available to them. And this has anything to do with gender, nor is it constructive to try to inject that into this community.