# Rails string dont allow empty string value in DB on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a model that looks like this in my schema.rb

```
create_table "runs", force: true do |t|
    ...
    t.string   "label", default: "Default Run Title", null: false
    ...
    t.datetime "timestamp"
end
```

However, when I create a new run leaving the label field blank in the form, It stores the run like:

```
=> #<Run... label: "", .....>
```

I want to force the default value set to `default: "Default Run Title` if the string is passed as an empty string.

What am I missing?

I suppose I can use a validator method or a before_save or something, but I'd rather have the model govern this behavior since this is well within the realm of what `default =>` is supposed to do I thought...

Comment: the problem is the "" != Null.    take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202319/rails-force-empty-string-to-null-in-the-database

Comment: Please show your params to the create method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting junk like that in your database schema is really, really annoying. What if later you need to change that phrasing? Then you need to run a migration. What if you want the phrasing to change based on the user's language? Then you need to write a hack to work around it.

What's better is to put this in your model:

```
before_validation :assign_default_label
```

Then later have a method that defaults it:

```
def assign_default_label
  return if (self.label?)

  self.label = "Default Run Title"
end
```

Any time you need to change that phrasing you can just re-deploy without having to alter the schema.

The `label?` method in a model will return true if there's a title assigned that contains something other than spaces. This means blank titles are replaced with whatever phrasing you want. These methods are automatically generated by ActiveRecord.

Comment: Thanks @tadman. Will title? work for label? Or will i have to write a custom label? method that does the same thing

Comment: Oh, right, I'll change the name there, got tripped up on your phrasing of "Default Run Title" not "Label". This principle will work on any string column.